# Staging several changes in one commit in Git?

Tags: git, commit, stage

I am watching a git course from Coursera.

There is a part that I don't understand where the instructor said, 'The separate step between staging and committing allows us to stage several changes in one commit.'

I am confused because, as far as I understood, the one commit command commits several changes, not stage several changes. If I want to stage changes, don't I have to call the git add command?

Please let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

**The separate step between staging and committing allows us to stage several changes in one commit.**

It stresses that *staging* (i.e. the `add` command) and *committing* being distinct steps, it allows for multiple staging rounds (if needed) before you commit.

But you can indeed stage everything then commit just once. It's not said (or even implied) that committing stages things. The subject of the sentence is *the separate step*)

What's unclear?

Comment: Thank you! I understood your clear explanation: It stresses that staging (i.e. the add command) and committing being distinct steps, it allows for multiple staging rounds (if needed) before you commit. 

I know that I can stage and commit at once. But I still don't get the separate step allows us to 'stage' several changes 'in one commit'. Yeah, the separate step is the subject, but 'we' can 'stage' changes 'in one commit,' not we can 'commit' staged changes 'in one commit,' which I think is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

> If I want to stage changes, don't I have to call the git add command?

You could, if you want to stage and then commit *all* changes:

```
git commit -am "all changes"
```

But if you want to commit some changes, you can prepare your next commit by first adding file to the cache.
See "[GitHowTo: Staging and committing](https://githowto.com/staging_and_committing)"

> A staging step in git allows you to continue making changes to the working directory, and when you decide you wanna interact with version control, it allows you to record changes in small commits.
>
> Suppose you have edited three files (`a.html`, `b.html`, and `c.html`).
> After that you need to commit all the changes so that the changes to `a.html` and `b.html` were a single commit, while the changes to `c.html` were not logically associated with the first two files and were done in a separate commit.
>
> In theory you can do the following:
>
> ```sh
> git add a.html
> git add b.html
> git commit -m "Changes for a and b"
> ```
>
> Then:
>
> ```sh
> git add c.html
> git commit -m "Unrelated change to c"
> ```
>
> Separating staging and committing, you get the chance to easily customize what goes into a commit.